# SQL IN clause with AND logic in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

Default IN uses OR base logic. Is there any way to use AND base logic with range.

For example in below query

```
SELECT ItemId,CategoryID
FROM ItemCategories
WHERE CategoryID IN (4,5)
```

One item can have multiple categories. considering following subset as items

```
|ItemID | CategoryID |
| 1     | 4          |
| 1     | 5          | 
| 2     | 4          |
| 2     | 6          |
| 3     | 4          |
| 3     | 5          |
```

Is there any way to exclude item2 ? Since Item 2 has category 6. I want items which MUST contain both 4 AND 5.

Using IN clause is not helping here. Also 4,5 range is dynamic.

Comment: How can a CategoryID be both 4 AND 5 at the same time?

Comment: Are you asking to how ensure that an `ItemID` exists for _both_ category 4, 5?

Comment: Depends on definition and usage of word Category. Several examples, consider category as kind of tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to using `IN ()` to merely limit the rowset, you need to verify that the `DISTINCT` set of `CategoryID` per `ItemID`.  To ensure that an item is present in both categories, verify that its aggregate `COUNT()` is 2 (equal to the number of items in your `IN ()`).

```
SELECT
  ItemID
FROM ItemCategories
WHERE CategoryID IN (4,5)
GROUP BY ItemID
-- When there are exactly 2 distinct categories
-- you can be certain that they are the 2 requested in the 
-- IN () clause
-- The value here must be equal to the number of items in the IN ()
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = 2
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9b6c/1

Note:  This will supply the set which has *exactly* that of your `IN ()` clause, and nothing else. If you need to include those which may have other categories not in the `IN ()`, just change it to `>=` instead of `=` in the `HAVING`.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) >= 2
```

Comment: What if he wants to match 3 categories, not two?  That he needs this to work specifically for combinations of exactly two categories is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Look at the comments in the query: _The value here must be equal to the number of items in the IN ()_ If the values in the IN () are dynamically generated, the same number of values must be used in the `HAVING` expression.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In other words, if the IN can be dynamically generated, so can the HAVING.

Comment: Ehh.  I don't think I'm buying it.  You're assuming dynamically-generated SQL, which the OP never mentioned.  However, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Edited question for better understanding "I want items which MUST contain both 4 AND 5."

Comment: @Nirav: I think we already get that.  But are you dynamically generating this SQL statement?  Will there ever be a different number of items in the IN than two?

Comment: @Nirav This will do it then.

Comment: Yes, already mentioned that IN clause is dynamic. I have comma seperated string from CSV which needs to pass in SQL

Comment: Issue is IN range uses OR base logic like CategoryID=4 OR CategoryID=5 OR ....I am looking for way which has AND logic in it

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you?

Comment: @Nirav You can't force `IN ()` to use AND logic alone. The idea here is that you must count the number of items you're passing to it (from your CSV) and insert that count into the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) = 2 looks fine. I did that too and wanted to see if there is another way. Waiting for few more min if any new idea comes or will mark your answer accepted.

Comment: Great proposal. I can even use it in JPA NamedNativeQueries.

Answer (score 1):

one convoluted way of doing this is

```
select itemid
from (
  select itemid, count(distinct categoryid) c
  from ItemCategories
  where categoryid in (4,5)
  group by itemid) a
where a.c = 2
```

here's another convoluted way:

```
select itemid, group_concat(distinct categoryid) g
from ItemCategories 
group by itemid
having find_in_set(4,g) and find_in_set(5,g);
```

if it's a range you are talking about:

```
select itemid
from (
  select itemid, count(distinct categoryid) c
  from ItemCategories
  where categoryid between 4 and 9
  group by itemid) a
where a.c = 9-4+1;
```

Comment: What if he wants to match 3 categories, not two?  That he needs this to work specifically for combinations of exactly two categories is extremely unlikely.

Comment: didn't know u meant a range :(

Comment: you missed 6 part :) may range mean was any set of dynamic random values.